# Adding a CALayer in TableViewCell triggers CALayerInvalid Exception

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Here is my subclass :

```
class SchedulingDatePickerTableViewCell:UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var fromPicker:UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var toPicker:UIDatePicker!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 128)
        border.backgroundColor = UIColor.SEMediumGrey().CGColor
        layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```

Adding the CALayer triggers the following exception :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer <CALayer: 0x7f8f3200eca0> is a part of cycle in its layer tree'
```

I don't get how that creates a cycle in the layer tree.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 8):

Eh I'm dumb.

I'm adding the layer into itself, not the one I created.

Comment: Just made the same mistake and found that I'm dumb too.

Comment:  same mistake, add me to the dumb group too.

Comment: Ah shucks. Alright, count me in. Where do I sign?